# JAVA Log4j : how write my own function with my own parameters

Tags: java, colors, log4j, pug

I would like to use Log4j on my java application, but I don't know how can I write something like a function who take my own parameters.

Currently my log look like this:

[My current log format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTdIn.png)

[java] [22:52:56][  GSM  ][INFO][read:SMS]    --START GSM [<-][read:SMS] --

```
 [java] [22:52:56][GSM][INFO][send:SMS] --START GSM [<-][send:SMS] --
 [java] [22:52:57][LadyBug][INFO][analyse]  --START LadyBug [analyse] --
 [java] [22:52:57][LadyBug][INFO][recv-ACL] --START LadyBug [recv-ACL] --
 [java] [22:52:57][LadyBug][INFO][MAIN] --START LadyBug--
 [java] [22:52:57][Console][INFO][recv-ACL] --START Console [recv-ACL] --
 [java] [22:52:57][Falcon ][DEBUG][initNumberOfEvents]  initNumberOfEvents=1327
 [java] [22:52:57][Console][INFO][analyse]  --START Console [analyse] --
 [java] [22:52:57][GSM][INFO][send:MAIL]    --START GSM [<-][send:MAIL] --
 [java] [22:52:57][GSM][INFO][recv-ACL] --START GSM [recv-ACL] --
 [java] [22:52:57][GSM][INFO][analyse]  --START GSM [->][analyse] --
 [java] [22:52:58][AgentCliXMPP][INFO][xmpp]    ----------- START -----------
 [java] [22:52:58][AgentCliXMPP][INFO][MAIN]    --START AgentCliXMPP--
 [java] [22:52:58][AgentCliXMPP][DEBUG][JabberSmackAPI] Login successful
 [java] [22:53:14][AgentCliXMPP][DEBUG][JabberSmackAPI] Received message from ***:coucouNULL
 [java] [22:53:14][AgentCliXMPP][INFO][JabberSmackAPI]  [<-]SEND-ACL|  {P:XMPP|Id:XMPP} to:LadyBug, content:{Chat->{vincent}[coucou]}
 [java] [22:53:14][LadyBug][INFO][BehaviorACL]  [->]RECV-ACL|  {P:XMPP|Id:XMPP} from:AgentCliXMPP content:{Chat->{vincent}[coucou]}
```

So I would like to learn how can I write if it's possible a personnalisable function.

Severity|AgentName|Thread|className|text

And for the next step, add some color like what I did on the screenshot.

Thank you in advance if you can help me.

Vost

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Log4J configuration guide](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html).  You shouldn't need to do too much other than setup the configuration file.  The colors are a bit more challenging as they will use an escape sequence but it can be embedded into the file too.